# PDFBox - document is empty after loading

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox for rendering thumbnails of PDF documents. Therefore I load the PDF and use the first page as thumbnail. The problem is, that for a particular document, it seems, it is not loaded correctly. For all other docs, it works like expected.

`ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfData);`

`PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(is, true);`

`List<PDPage> pages = pdf.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages(); //pages is empty here`

The pdf file has 238 pages and is around 6,5 MB of size.

Comment: try loadNonSeq(is,null) - does it work then?

Comment: thanks, loadNonSeq works. As I didn't find any documentation, do you know, if there is a significant performance impact, if loadNonSeq is used instead of load?

Comment: Could be. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2860 However the nonSeq parser is the correct one. The old one no longer exists in the 2.0 version. However the most time is spent in rendering, not parsing (depending on the size of images).

Comment: OK, thanks, then I will go with loadNonSeq and observe the performance.

Comment: I've added an answer so that the question isn't an orphan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using an 1.8.* version, please use the non sequential parser:

```
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(is, null);
```

The non sequential parser is successful in certain cases where the old parser fails, e.g. for PDFs that have had revisions ([example](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2567)). Another advantage is that no extra code is needed for "protected" PDFs that are encrypted with the empty password.

Comment: *The non sequential parser*, furthermore, parses more according to the specification, i.e. more correctly, yet another advantage...

Comment: Hint: current version is 1.8.10 :-)